# MongoDB - how to dynamically change key

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new to MongoDB. I was wondering how MongoDB implements "variable Interpolation" ?

I have following code

```
for (i=0;i<3;i++){
db.test2.insert({i:i+1}); 
}
```

Which insert

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("564a1bd0987fe676b9cad025"), "i" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("564a1bd0987fe676b9cad026"), "i" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("564a1bd0987fe676b9cad027"), "i" : 3 }
```

But I want

```
  { "_id" : ObjectId("564a1bd0987fe676b9cad025"), "0" : 1 }
  { "_id" : ObjectId("564a1bd0987fe676b9cad026"), "1" : 2 }
  { "_id" : ObjectId("564a1bd0987fe676b9cad027"), "2" : 3 }
```

Mongo does not changes value in key part.  How to fit it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to build your query dynamically.

```js
var documents = [];
for(var i=0; i<3; i++) {
    var doc = {};
    doc[i] = i;
    documents.push(doc);
}

db.collection.insert(documents)
```

Then `db.collection.find()` yields:

```js
{ "_id" : ObjectId("564a2296c68c7068c12fb206"), "0" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("564a2296c68c7068c12fb207"), "1" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("564a2296c68c7068c12fb208"), "2" : 2 }
```

**Note that it's not a good practice to have string of integer as field's name**